# is pkt_duration_time in ffmpeg constant?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

When I am looking at pkt_duration_time using ffprobe, it looks constant through out my video. I wanted to know can we have varying pkt_duration_time for different parts of same video file?

```
ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v -print_format json=c=1 -unit test.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the file. By some files may be variable frame rate.